# Is there a way to change prefixed c-childfunction to myteamname-childfunction?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

As title says, I was wondering if it is possible to change the name of calling a component from `<c-childfunction></c-childfunction>` to `<myteamname-childfunction></myteamname-childfunction>` as it would be better for readability on a larger scale application. If this is possible what setting would I have to alter to have as above? Would it also have the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [LWC OSS](https://lwc.dev/), you can use whatever prefix you want. Simply store the file in something like `myteamname/componentname/`, and you'll have the ability to use that prefix instead of `c`.

However, if you're using this in Salesforce, you'd have to [create a namespace](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.register_namespace_prefix.htm&type=5) (e.g. `myteamns`), enable the [Dev Hub](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm&type=5) functionality, link the [namespace to the dev hub org](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sfdx_dev_reg_namespace.htm&type=5), create a [Second Generation Managed Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp.htm), and then finally you could install that package and reference it in outside code as `<myteamns-childfunction>`...

Basically, the `c` part up front is "this org's namespace," or, equivalently, "the current namespace." Using a different namespace from `c` involves having a managed package. Salesforce uses this to prevent collisions from different components from different developers that would otherwise have the same name. It's typically meant for ISV partners to enable their subscribers to have multiple packages from different ISVs installed at once.

Note that within the managed package, you'd still use the `c` namespace, it'd only be different outside of the package (e.g. in a different package that specifies your managed package as a dependency). Using Managed Packages also means you're subject to a ton of restrictions, like not being able to easily delete or rename components, etc. It's a lot of effort just for a bit of effect, and probably not worth it if you're not planning on selling your package on the AppExchange.

Comment: ah okay, this makes perfect sense. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!